# Can mem copy be implemented without any pointer arithmetic in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

Implementation of my_memcpy (memory copy from source to destination based on size) uses a lot of pointer arithmetic, which is a very common method of implementation.

Issue: Based on certain standards, my code is not supposed to use pointer arithmetic, but can use arrays.

Is there any way we can implement that function without using any pointer arithmetic?

I want the below logic to be implemented without the use of pointers:

```
while (u32_length >= SIZE)
{
    *u32p_dst = *u32p_src;  
     u32p_dst++;
     u32p_src++;
     u32_length -= SIZE;            
}
....
....
```

Comment: please show your code and point out where do you want do modifications.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the standard `memcpy()`? If you write it yourself, you have one more piece of code to maintain.

Comment: @BenS: Its on an embedded system. No libraries are present. We should write our own.

Comment: I don't know where you're coding standards come from, so you might be stuck with them, but I feel I should point out that arrays _are_ pointer arithmetic. Not figuratively, but literally - `myArray[3]` is the same as `*(myArray + 3)`. You can tell because, believe it or not, `3[myArray]` gives the same results - the square brackets are basically treated like a macro (according to the standard, anyway - some compilers might complain or try to protect you from this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about the following,

```
unsigned i = 0;
while(u32_length >= SIZE){
   u32p_dst[i] = u32p_src[i];
   ++ i; 
   u32_length -= SIZE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you can treat the pointer and an array element the same here

to improve performance, normally using a pointer is faster(but in most cases this is not the bottleneck)